# Unix command to remove space from a file name

Tags: rename, filenames, whitespace

I have a file whose file name has a space like `First Name_20180810.csv`. The date (`20180810` in the above example) changes daily in the filename. 
How can I rename `First Name_*.csv` to be `FirstName_*.csv`?

Comment: difficult to understand, try using the blockquote or code sample to enter the file name or commands from body toolbar while drafting your question

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911301/rename-multiple-files-in-shell ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have access to the `rename` tool, this should work:

```bsh
for file in *.csv; do
    if ! [[ -f "${file// /}" ]]; then
        mv "$file" "${file// /}"
    else
        echo "Replacement for '${file}' already exists; skipping"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` when doing any sort of bulk move/rename, to avoid silent and irreversible data loss in case there are any name conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename` command:

```
rename "s/ //g" *.csv
```

[`man rename` :examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm)